# How to download a CSV file from a website if the download button does not have a URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping

This [website](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener) has "Download CSV" button, but it does not lead to a specific URL that I can just call from inside a Python or R program. Is there a way to do it autonomously?

Normally, in Python, I would do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('csv_url')
```

But since the NASDAQ website lacks a URL, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Looking around in the code on that website, it looks like the site gets data from JSON that it requests from the url `https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true`

Since it probably does not need to be a CSV, this is probably OK for your use.

```
data = pd.read_json("https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true")
```

From testing, it seems like the only important parameter of that URL is the `download=true`, so it can be simplified to `https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?download=true`.

Comment: I'm a but confused on how to convert this JSON to a dataframe... tried pd.read_json and some other things and nothing worked... any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let me tell you how I did it, then I'll tell you a better way to do it.

The buttons isn't a `<href>` like you are used to. It's calling some javascript to pull the CSV.

Using chrome, I opened inspector (Ctrl+I), then switched to the network tab. I clicked the button and just looked for an incoming csv. This gave me the url where you can download the data.

```
 https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true
```

For some reason, it's returning a json, not a csv, but you should still be able to read it with

```
  pd.read_json(https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true)
```

Now here is the right way to use this site. NASDAQ has an API that is [documented here](https://dataondemand.nasdaq.com/docs/index.html). Using thier API will give you a more reliable and stable data connection without having to resort to tricks like using Chrome's inspector.

Comment: Makes sense! I tried this, but the command just loads infinitely, even for a very small json file here: https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?marketcap=mega&country=united_states|usa&download=true. I assume they block such requests?